# IEEEtran BSTcontrol does not work

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, bst

The section "The IEEEtran BST control entry type" in "How to use IEEEtran Bibtex Style" document describes how could one use omit URLs and use "et al" in the bibliography. Unfortunately it does not seem to work in my case, and I was not able to find any other description. There is nothing in the log file indicating that the `bstcontrol.bib` has been loaded. The build directory contains `IEEEtran.bst` and `IEEEtran.cls` as well. What am I missing? What else should be set up to make it work?

My mwe LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \cite{key}
  \bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
  \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
  \bibliography{bstctrl,mwe}
\end{document}
```

The `bstcontrol.bib` file:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
  CTLuse_forced_etal       = "yes",
  CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "6",
  CTLnames_show_etal       = "1",
  CTLuse_url               = "no",
  CTLdash_repeated_names   = "no"
}
```

The `mwe.bib` file:

```
@book{key,
  author = {A,a and B,b and C,c and D,d and E,e and F,f and G,g and H,h and I,i },
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  url = {https://mysite/mybook/index.html},
}
```

The contains the URL and the long author list has not been reduced with "et al.":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you've encountered is that if a bibliography style -- such as `IEEEtran` -- is in use that does *not* sort the bibliography entries (generally alphabetically by authors' surnames), the `\bstctlcite` command must come *before* any "regular" `\cite` commands. Indeed, the [IEEEtran BST HowTo document](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) recommends placing the `\bstctlcite` directive immediately after `\begin{document}` (see p. 8 of the user guide, right-hand column).

Hence, give the following test document a try:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol} % make this the first directive after "\begin{document}"
  \lipsum[1]
  \cite{key}
  \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
  \bibliography{bstcontrol,mwe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In hindsight it is easy to find. I remember reading that part of the documentation, and I skipped to the next paragraph after reading "For unsorted Bibtex style".